# Fire a js function on click for multiple elements with the same id

Tags: javascript, html, gridview, onclick

I have a number of links inside my ASP grid view. Each link is supposed to fire a Javascript function after clicking it by calling their respective ID. Here is the code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#LkForgot').on('click', function (e) {
      alert("hi");
    });
  });
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ReportId"CssClass="GridViewStyle">
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="Link" ID="IMGDetail" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/Detail.png" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

All of them have the same ID, but only the first one successfully fires the function. I want each link to separately fire the function.

Comment: have the same class for all and use the selector as ('.classname') to listen to the events

Comment: You can use the CSS selector in JQuery to bind the `click` event to all the element that have the `link` class inside your specific `GridView` like following : `$("#GridView1 .Link").click(function() { alert("hi"); });`.

Comment: same id ! will that comply HTML standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.Link').on('click', function (e) {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't now about asp but IDs are supposed to be unique. Try populating the IDs dynamically or try using classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ID and it should unique , that's why it will work on only one element try with class. You can apply same class to multiple element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.LkForgot').on('click', function (e) {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify a unique attribute in the element and use that as the unique identifier. It does not always have to be the 'id'  tag. you could do something like this as well

```
$("[ClientIDMode='Static']").bind("click", function(){console.log("clicked") })
```